# Why is Prop not applied to component in component library vue js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, mdbootstrap

I am busy moving my components from our projects into a component library for ease of use and maintainability purposes.
I am using this [Vue/Nuxt Library template](https://github.com/wuruoyun/vue-component-lib-starter)  following the structure and processes outlined.

Currently I only have 2 components in there a TestButton.vue and a LoaderModal.vue .

[image]

The test button works fine when imported/called from an application when it sits in the library as it shows as expected and looks like it should as it is actually a mdb button (which I just used to test component imports). [(we use MDB as our main component lib](https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/vue/components/buttons/)

The problem is with the Loading Modal. Normally you would set the show property of the modal to show or hide it like so.

```html
<template>
  <mdb-modal centered :show="showLoader">
    <mdb-modal-body class="text-center">
      <div class="d-flex justify-content-center" v-if="selectedLoader==='BALL'">
        <div class="spinner-grow" role="status" style="color: #005250; width: 3rem; height: 3rem;">
          <span class="sr-only">Loading...</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <h3 class="block" style="margin-top:16px" v-if="longLoadingText!=null">{{ longLoadingText }}</h3>
      <h3 class="block" style="margin-top:16px" v-else>{{ text }}</h3>
    </mdb-modal-body>
  </mdb-modal>
</template>
```

using props to show,hide and control text like so

```html
 props: {
    showLoader: { default: true, type: Boolean },
    text: { default: "Loading", type: String },
  },
```

and it works fine if I run it in the component library itself using

> vue serve ./src/components/LoaderModal

but when I set the showLoader prop to true from the application that imports the library it does not show. I can see the modal is in the DOM but the display is set to none.
There are no errors in the console and if I change the Display to "block" the LoadingModal Shows.

Here is the html copied from the DOM that shows it is there, but display is just set to "none"

```html
<div data-v-bfb6b926="" data-v-6a672d6c="" class="modal" style="opacity: 1;">
  <div data-v-bfb6b926="" role="document" class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" style="transform: translate(0px, 0px);">
    <div data-v-bfb6b926="" class="modal-content">
      <div data-v-c35b1502="" data-v-6a672d6c="" class="text-center modal-body">
        <div data-v-6a672d6c="" data-v-c35b1502="" class="d-flex justify-content-center">
          <div data-v-6a672d6c="" data-v-c35b1502="" role="status" class="spinner-grow" style="color: rgb(0, 82, 80); width: 3rem; height: 3rem;"><span data-v-6a672d6c="" data-v-c35b1502="" class="sr-only">Loading...</span></div>
        </div>
        <!---->
        <!---->
        <h3 data-v-6a672d6c="" data-v-c35b1502="" class="block" style="margin-top: 16px;">Loading some stuff</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

> My Library Package.json looks as follow

```html
{
  "name": "@myScope/web-commons",
  "version": "0.1.23",
  "private": false,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build --report --target lib --name web-commons ./src/index.js",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint",
    "docs:build": "vuepress build docs",
    "docs:dev": "vuepress dev docs"
  },
  "main": "dist/web-commons.common.js",
  "files": [
    "src",
    "assets",https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63504989/edit#
    "dist/*.{js,css}"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "mdbvue": "^6.7.1",
    "vue": "^2.6.11"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/babel-preset-app": "^4.4.6",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^4.4.6",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^4.4.6",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^4.4.6",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "eslint": "^7.3.1",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^6.2.2",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11",
    "vuepress": "^1.5.2"
  }
}
```

and the plugin looks as follows in my main project.

```html
import Vue from 'vue'
import * as componets from '@myScope/web-commons'
Vue.use(componets)
```

Then it is also added to the nuxt.config as a plugin.
Please help

**EDIT**
Below is the value of the props from the vue dev panel
[image]

> Update

The following is the link to the codesandbox project for the component library. The library is also on Npm. Try using the LoaderModal Component in any nuxt project to see problem.
[Code Sandbox Component Library](https://codesandbox.io/s/quirky-sun-lkuhh?file=/src/install.js)

[Component Implementation Example Nuxt js](https://codesandbox.io/s/distracted-shadow-if4k6?file=/pages/index.vue)

Comment: In the DOM that you said there is not any display none ! so I don't understand what is your problem ?!

Comment: Hi @soroush no sorry for my bad structuring of the sentence but I said there is a display and it is set to none, and normally when passed in the ":show" prop the display would change to block

Comment: when you debug with the dev tool do you see the prop being passed?

Comment: Yes @JonathanAkweteyOkine the prop value is passed as expected (Please see my update for information), but its as if there is no such element attribute for the mdb modal prop "show".

Comment: can you provide a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) of your codes??

Comment: I don't get which is your library which is usage? Can you provide an example to clear it like @tuhin47 said?

Comment: @tuhin47 please see provided sandbox for library code and implementation thereof.

Comment: if for some reason you are not looking for what @tuhin47 mentioned then ping me on skype: syed_haroon - let's fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual problem seem to have been that all the required css components of the mdblibrary was not being import despite being imported in the index of the component library.

It seems that when adding a plugin to nuxt it calls the install method and nothing else. The solution was to import the css into the component itself and making it "scoped" otherwise it will affect the components in the main application.

```css
<style
scoped
>
@import "../../node_modules/mdbvue/lib/css/mdb.min.css"; 
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I see your `codesandbox`. There is a small mistake using the props in your code for `LoaderModal` component. If you use a value directly for the `props` you don't need to bind (`:text`) it. So you can use the component as below.

```
<LoaderModal :showLoader="true" text="Some Loading Text"/>
```

if you use a data element as a props then bind it:

```
<LoaderModal :showLoader="true" :text="variableName"/>
```

Here is the working [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/naughty-morse-imko2?file=/pages/index.vue) of your codesandbox

Comment: Thank you for the attempt that the suggested solution does not work, also not on the provided link. The issue is with the modal that is not showing even though I can see the prop value is set to true. And normally the "text" prop is populated with a variable requiring it to be bound, but for the sake of the example it left it out.